# How can I find what VENUE_ID I need for places other than the Zurich Airport in the HERE API?

Tags: here-api

I am currently using the HERE Maps Javascript API (which from what I understand is different than the Venue Maps REST API) to load up indoor maps of places on an Angular app. I am able to run the example shown in the link below just fine, but I'm struggling to figure out how to find other Venue_ID's on this API other than the hardcoded 7348 linked to the Zurich Airport.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/data/venues-on-map

From what I read online, things like the Venue Index are available on the different REST API, and that one has different Venue_ID's so it wouldn't help. I also don't think it provides the level of detail I need. Do any of you know a solution to finding/using different VENUE_ID's with the Javascript API? The code in question is below, it is related to the loadVenue() method I believe.

```
        // Venues provider interacts with tile layer to visualize and control the venue map
        const venuesProvider = new H.venues.Provider();
  
        // Venues service provides a loadVenue method
        venuesService.loadVenue(7348).then((venue) => {
            
        // add venue data to venues provider
        venuesProvider.addVenue(venue);
        venuesProvider.setActiveVenue(venue);
```

Answer (score 0):

The access to venue maps is controlled. If you are interested in leveraging HERE Venues with the Maps API for Javascript, contact us at venues.support@here.com.

Answer (score 0):

I learned this functonality does not yet exist with the HERE API. The example with the Zurich airport is the only one that's available.